# Change value of button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

```
<div>
<button type="button" style="width:250px;"onclick="loadMenu('menu_${bookings.bookingId}')" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">View Items</button>
</div>

<div id="menu_${bookings.bookingId}" style="display: none;">
    ${bookings.products}
</div>
```

I want to change the value of **view items** to **hide items** when i click on that button

**MY SCRIPt**

```
function loadMenu(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'block')
{
   e.style.display = 'none';
   }
    else{
       e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: you can give your button an id and do this: `document.getElementById('yourbuttonId').innerHTML = "Show items"` in your if statement and reverse in your else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should use an unobtrusive event handler instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes.

From there, you can use the `this` keyword to reference the clicked button and toggle its text based on its current value. Try this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.booking-toggle').forEach(function() {
  this.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var id = e.target.getAttribute('data-bookingid');
    var booking = document.getElementById(id);
    booking.style.display = booking.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    e.target.innerText = e.target.innerText == 'View Items' ? 'Hide Items' : 'View Items';
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" style="width:250px;" data-bookingid="bookingId_1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm booking-toggle" id="foo">View Items</button>
</div>

<div id="bookingId_1" style="display: none;">
  ${bookings.products}
</div>
```

Or in jQuery:

```js
$('.booking-toggle').click(function() {
  var $btn = $(this);
  $('#' + $btn.data('bookingid')).toggle();
  $btn.text(function(i, t) {
      return t == 'View Items' ? 'Hide Items' : 'View Items';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button type="button" style="width:250px;" data-bookingid="bookingId_1" class="btn btn-default btn-sm booking-toggle" id="foo">View Items</button>
</div>

<div id="bookingId_1" style="display: none;">
  ${bookings.products}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear Demo and code:

html

```
<button  id="button" href="#">Show/Hide</button>
<div id="item">Item</div>
```

js:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
$( "#item" ).toggle();
});
```

replace the link with button:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/
```

another example

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/